# Ljava.lang.Object

Tags: android, xml-rpc

I am using `XMLRPC Webservice` to execute this command:

```
Object result = client.call("user.GetVirtualList",AccountNo);
```

The problem is I cant see whats inside the list:

```
{
  list=[Ljava.lang.Object;@45007f78, isSuccess=true
}
```

Comment: you did not cast the object to the kind of instance it is and iterate what is within that object for it's results.

Comment: @XepterX so sorry i'm a beginner , meaning?

Comment: do you know like what Object result is?? for example like result could be a instance of AccountNumber, then you cast it to AccountNumber resultCast = (AccountNumber) result, then you iterate resultCast to get the values.

Comment: Casting it to Object is generic,everything in java is an object, that is why you could not get the list. it does not know what kind of object it is

Comment: @XepterX thanks for explaining it to me! so meaning my code should be: AccountNumber resultCast = (AccountNumber) result ? Then when i iterate is to see the values in it right?

Comment: i'm not sure what kind of object it is so AccountNo might not be the right cast, you would have to try and find out what kind of object that is =)

Comment: @XepterX thanks so much! I give it try.